# Karaf service on Windows does not allow install with a mvn url for source location

Tags: maven, apache-karaf

I have an application where the maven build installs bundles using mvn urls into karaf ( using the karaf client )  On windows this works fine when karaf is opened normally, but when I start karaf as a service with

> install mvn:[GroupId]/[ArtifactId]/[version]

it fails to find the bundle in the local repository. However I am able to install with a file url .  I suspected that it could be because it could not find the .m2 repository which is in my home directory , when karaf is running as a service in admin mode, but could not find a way of configuring karaf to point to the right local repository.

Any help/pointers would be welcome.

Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the mvn repository directly in etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg.

To the bottom of this file, you have commented examples of how to configure your own org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories. (@snapshots, @noreleases, ...)